# angularjs filter not executing in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm running AngularJS 1.2.22 and I seem to be having trouble with IE9 and a custom filter that I wrote.  It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but ,of course, not the browser I really need.

I have two filters in an <i> tag: one to return a font awesome icon name and the other to provide a color style.  The problem is that one filter runs okay which gives me the icon name, but not the other, which gives me color.

Here's my HTML

```
<td>
    <i tooltip="{{d.Validation}}" class='fa {{d.StatusIndicator | statusIcon}}'
        style="color: {{d.StatusIndicator | statusIconColor}}; font-size: 1.25em;"></i>
</td>
```

And my filter source:

```
app.filter('statusIcon', function() {
    return function(item) {
        switch (item) {
        case 'Y':
            return "fa-exclamation-circle";
        case 'R':
            return "fa-exclamation-triangle";
        case 'G':
            return "fa-check-circle";
        default:
            return "";
        }
    };
});

app.filter('statusIconColor', function() {
    return function(item) {
        switch (item) {
        case 'Y':
            return "#B2B200";
        case 'R':
            return "red";
        case 'G':
            return "green";
        default:
            return "green";
        }
    };
});
```

When I open dev tools on Firefox and IE, I can see the 'color' style rendered properly in Firefox, but there is no 'color' style at all in IE.  I see breakpoint hits in the 'statusIconColor' filter in Firefox, but not in IE which is what led me to believe the filter isn't even being invoked in IE.

A breakpoint in the the 'statusIcon' filter hits in both browsers, but not in 'statusIconColor'.  Wierd!

And there are no console error messages.

I'd appreciate any advice.
Corey.

Comment: maybe if you try the [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directives instead of `style` and `class` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the case when you should use `ngAttrStyle` directive:

```
ng-attr-style="color: {{d.StatusIndicator | statusIconColor}}; font-size: 1.25em;"
```

However I would use ngStyle better and avoid filters for this purpose. You can use controller functions instead.

Apparently IE applies these styles `color: {{d.StatusIndicator | statusIconColor}}; font-size: 1.25em;` literally, so `ngAttrStyle` directive sets `style` attribute  only after it's interpolated.

Comment: This sounds awesome, but does the directive actually exist for real? I can't seem to find any documentation about it on https://docs.angularjs.org, and it doesn't work when I try it... (Angular 1.2.28)

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson Yes, of course: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings, it's should be available in Angular 1.2.x.

Comment: Aha, I was looking for ngAttrStyle, but it's a generic programming construct, ngAttr. Cool, thanks.